# Zabbix script timeout

Tags: powershell, scripting, monitoring, zabbix

I'm trying to run powershell script for cleaning disk on agent from Zabbix. Seems that script is running too long and instead response I got error.

```
powershell -NonInteractive C:\Scripts\CleanDisk.ps1 -deleteLogsOlderThanDays 10
```

Script deletes some logs and temp folders and prints statistics. If there is only few folders to delete it work fines. But if script runs too long then dialog windows with script result ends with error **Get value from agent failed: ZBX_TCP_READ**

Guess that it's because connection to client timeout. Is there some way how to get over this limitation? 
Thx

Comment: Zabbix version 2.4

Comment: How are you running it from the Zabbix side - is it a userparameter, a remote command or some other way ?

Comment: It's remote command, I think.To add new: Administration > Scripts > Add new... To run: Monitoring > Maps > Left click on some item and select script to run

Comment: Where do you see the error message?

Comment: When you go Monitoring > Maps. In right Dorp-Down select required map. On map find host and select it's icon by left mouse button click. From context menu select script. This will start script on selected host agent and it's result appear in new dialog window. Ignore it I found workaround.

Comment: Please don't extend your question with comments. Instead edit your question and add e.g. the version of Zabbix. In most cases it's worth the identify the changes with a `*Edit:*` in front of the addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleagues found usable workaround. Instead of starting script which will run long time it's better to only schedule script with schtask.exe. So I modified script, now it contains two parts. One is responsible for scheduling and starting scheduled task (schedule it self but with different arguments), second heavy and long running does the action. Result of scheduling will appear in execution script dialog box in zabbix, result of long running action is going to log file...

Here is example of powershell script StartCleanDisk.ps1. In this case task will be scheduled and immediately executed by scheduler.

```
StartCleanDisk.ps1 -deleteLogsOlderThanDays 10 -startAsTask 1
```

In this case task will directly executed.

```
StartCleanDisk.ps1 -deleteLogsOlderThanDays 10 -startAsTask 0
```

StartCleanDisk.ps1 content:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int]
    $deleteLogsOlderThanDays,
    [bool]
    $startAsTask = $false
)

if ($startAsTask)
{
    Write-Output "Scheduling task for cleaning disk ...";

  $taskname = "CleanDisk"
    $logFile = "X:\logs\Tasks\cleaningDisk.log";
    $task = "powershell $PSScriptRoot\StartCleanDisk.ps1 -deleteLogsOlderThanDays $deleteLogsOlderThanDays -startAsTask 0 > $logFile 2>&1";
    & schtasks /create /ru "System" /tn $taskname /tr $task /sc once /ST 23:59 /F /V1 /Z;
    Write-Output "Task Clean disk created...";
    & schtasks /run /tn $taskname;
    Write-Output "Task $taskname started... Please chek $logFile";
    exit 0;
}

#####################
# Script begins here
# PUT HERE COMMANDS FOR DELETING
#####################
```

Answer (score 0):

Start as a hidden process

```
UserParameter=Key[*],powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList \\Path\SYSVOL\..\scripts\Files\Zabbix\Key.$1.ps1 "$2" "$3" -Windowstyle Hidden
```

Where Key[*] is an active item in Zabbix agent for start powershell at windows host,
$1 for variation of name PowerShell scrips, "`$2" "$3" "next"` for any parameters

if `$1="Ring"` then the name of the script will Key.Ring.ps1